# How to create ASP.NET Web Forms project in Visual Studio 2022 using Empty template?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2022

All of the tutorials that I have seen use ASP.NET Web application (.NET Framework) template in Visual Studio to create webforms projects. But Visual Studio 2022 does not come with ASP.NET Web application (.NET Framework) template. I understand that we can get that option by adding additional components in Visual Studio 2022, however my question is that can we create a webforms project using some of the default templates available in VS 2022?

Can I create a Web Forms application project using "Empty Project (.NET Framework)" template? If yes, how to do that?

[image]

Comment: The templates are just used to generate files. There's nothing stopping you from creating an Empty Project and then hand editing the files it generates until they match what the templates would have generated for a Web Forms project.

Comment: This youtube channel has some videos that create blank ASP.NET project: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpYjwfqGjUsrH1shSOMx74w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the templates and webforms is quite old?
And since Visual Studio gets a boatload of features every year?

Well, after 20+ years, Visual Studio has become massive, but absolute massive.

So, by default, not all of the webforms templates are installed.

You need to add a few more workflows and templates.

So, from VS, tools->Get Tools and Features.

Make sure you selected these:

[image]

The "class designer" of course does not matter, but it is nice to have. Same goes for the RDLC Report Designer if you used the web-based report builder in the past.

And in the above list, I recommend all of the Optional choices I have in above.

Once done, then you find the traditional WebForms "web site" option (I recommend you don't use such projects), and you find the WebForms web site Application which is of course the recommended type of project to choose when building web forms applications.

Thus choose 1 of theses (vb.net, or c#).

[image]

## Edit: Adding some assemblies (additional references)

So, starting out with a blank (empty) asp.net webforms application?

The process of adding references is much the same as when building some desktop software, or even console applications. Or even building a .net class project without any UI at all.

So, we can create a blank (empty) new web project with the above choice:

Hence this:

[image]

Then next and this:

[image]

And then this choice:

[image]

So, you probably can un-check the https setting.

So, now with above, we have a blank empty project.

And to add references, then you can simple right click on references in the project explorer, and choose to add.

The process looks like this:

[image]

So, how to add additional assemblies and references to a project is not any different when building desktop software, console applications, or as in this example, working with an empty asp.net application.

Comment: Thank you. My question was more about if its possible to create web forms project using Empty Project (.NET Framework) template by adding assembly references to it? If yes, how. I couldnt find any information on that.

Comment: See my edit, I show how to add assembles to a empty web project. However, if you don't start out with a empty webforms project, then no, some simple adding of some simple reference will never work. I mean, when you go to add a new form, what kind of form? (desktop, WFP, WebForms, MVC.....). The project HAS to know the project type (along with 200+ assumptions about that new "thing" being added to the project. So MASSIVE BOATLOADS of settings and assumptions are required for Visual to "help you" create such projects and wire things up correctly. This goes way beyond some simple reference.